# How to prove $\sqrt[3]{\frac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}{3}}\ge \frac{\sqrt[3]{abc}+2}{\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}}.$

Tags: inequality, radicals

> If $a,b,c>0: a+b+c=3$ then$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}}{3}}\ge \frac{\sqrt[3]{abc}+2}{\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}}.$$

I can prove the following inequality$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}}{3}}\ge \frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}}.$$It is weaker than the starting one because $\sqrt[3]{abc}+2\ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}\iff 1\ge \sqrt[3]{abc}.$

We may use Cauchy-Schwarz $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\ge \frac{9}{a+b+c}=3$$and by AM-GM $$\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}\ge 3\sqrt[9]{a^2b^2c^2}\ge   3\sqrt[3]{abc}.$$
But I can not use same idea for the starting inequality.

Can you help me? Thank you.

*Update.*

I also tried AM-GM $$\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\ge \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}$$
Thus, we need to prove
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[9]{abc}}\ge \frac{\sqrt[3]{abc}+2}{\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}}.$$
But I don't know how to continue the proof.

Comment: can $\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}}{3}\right)^2\ge \sqrt[3]{\frac{(a+b+c)abc}{3}}$ be proven?

Comment: Cute problem. After normalization, it's equivalent to:
$$\left(\sum x^3y^3\right)\left(\sum x \right)^3\left(\sum x^3\right)\geq\left(2\sum x^3y^3 + 3x^2y^2z^2\right)^3$$
which someone with a good SOS program can probably brute force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof.**

Indeed, we'll prove

$$\sqrt[3]{\left(\dfrac{1}{a^3}+\dfrac{1}{b^3}+\dfrac{1}{c^3}\right)\cdot (a^3+b^3+c^3)^2}\ge \frac{3abc+2(a^3+b^3+c^3)}{ab+bc+ca}.$$Based on symmetric principle, we may prove$$\sqrt[3]{b^3c^3\left(\dfrac{1}{a^3}+\dfrac{1}{b^3}+\dfrac{1}{c^3}\right)\cdot (a^3+b^3+c^3)^2}\ge b^3+c^3+abc,$$or$$\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{b^3c^3}{a^3}+b^3+c^3\right)\cdot (a^3+b^3+c^3)\cdot (a^3+b^3+c^3)}\ge b^3+c^3+abc,$$which is true by Holder inequality
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{b^3c^3}{a^3}+b^3+c^3\right)\cdot (a^3+b^3+c^3)\cdot (a^3+b^3+c^3)}&\ge \sqrt[3]{\frac{b^3c^3}{a^3}\cdot a^3\cdot a^3} +\sqrt[3]{b^3\cdot b^3\cdot b^3}+\sqrt[3]{c^3\cdot c^3\cdot c^3}\\&=b^3+c^3+abc.
\end{align*}
Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds iff $a=b=c=1.$

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt[3]{ab}\sqrt[3]{\frac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}{3}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{a+b+\frac{ab}{c}}{3}}\\
={}&\frac1{3}\sqrt[3]{(a+b+c)(a+b+c)\Big(a+b+\frac{ab}{c}\Big)}\geqslant\frac1{3}(a+b+\sqrt[3]{abc}).
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac})\sqrt[3]{\frac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}{3}}\geqslant\frac23(a+b+c)+\sqrt[3]{abc}\\
\iff{}& \begin{aligned}
\sqrt[3]{\frac{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}}{3}}\ge \frac{\sqrt[3]{abc}+2}{\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}}
\end{aligned}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Either the problem is simple or I cannot find my mistake.

Do a homogenization by $a\to \frac{1}{x^3}$ etc and it suffices to prove:
$$\left(\sum x^3y^3\right)^2\left(\sum x \right)^3\left(\sum x^3\right)\geq\left(2\sum x^3y^3 + 3x^2y^2z^2\right)^3.$$
WLOG assume now $x\geq y\geq z$ and
use Holder for the first and third product term in the LHS:
$$\sum x^3y^3\sum x^3y^3\sum x^3\geq \left(\sum_{cyc} x^3y^2\right)^3$$
so now after taking cube roots from both sides, we need to show:
$$LHS = \sum x\sum_{cyc} x^3y^2\geq 2\sum x^3y^3 + 3x^2y^2z^2 = RHS$$
But after opening the brackets and simplifying, one can easily see that this is the same as:
$$LHS - RHS = \left(\sum_{cyc} x^4y^2-\sum x^3y^3\right) + xyz\left(\sum_{cyc} x^2y-3xyz\right)\geq 0.$$
Now we are basically done since both summands above are non-negative. The second one is just AM-GM and the first one follows from our assumption of $x\geq y\geq z:$
$$2\left(\sum_{cyc} x^4y^2-\sum x^3y^3\right)\geq \sum_{cyc} x^4y^2 + \sum_{cyc} x^2y^4 - 2\sum x^3y^3 = \sum x^2y^2(x-y)^2\geq 0.$$

Comment: How do you apply AM-GM? I know that by Muirhead 
$$
\sum_{cyc}xyz=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{sym}xyz\leq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{sym}x^2y\leq\sum_{cyc}x^2y.
$$

Comment: @V.S.e.H. just apply the 3 person AM-GM directly

Comment: Do you include $3xyz$ in the sum? It makes no sense then, so maybe you meant to just write $xyz$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. it is not in the sum - if it were, I would write:
$$\sum (x^2y-3xyz)$$

Comment: Yes, that makes sense! Anyway, I wouldn't know what you would write otherwise, but in its current form, besides being a bit confusing in notation, I can't find any mistakes in your answer. I'd be very nice to clarify a bit your notation, by including extra parentheses where necessary. Good job!